# Getting error even the package is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new learner. I installed openpyxl module. And I have it in my directory. But when I want to use it I get error :

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'"
```

any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where's your code?

Comment: please show main codes

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: Is the module is installed directory which is part of your environment path? Else it won't be detected. Also try to restart your kernel.

Comment: would you mind to add your code.

Comment: I'm going to simply use a excel file so here is the code:                                 import openpyxl
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('test4time.xlsx') but I get this error:                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pamiran\New folder\tests\test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Comment: @PedroLobito thnx man

Comment: @busybear I used command prompt and typed pip3 install openpyxl      and when I checked I saw the package in my c drive but the program does not work

Comment: @AshuGrover how can I change that? and what's Kernel?! :D :) I'm a new learner.

Comment: My guess is you have multiple python installations. Make sure you are installing to the same python you are using. `where pip3` might be useful in figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors (`ModuleNotFoundError`) is usually caused due to various versions of Python being installed on your system. If you have both Python 2 and 3 installed, use `pip2` or `pip3` to install your module.

```
pip2 install openpyxl  # for python2
pip3 install openpyxl  # for python3
```